# Check if folder is empty outputs error (PHP)

Tags: php, dir, opendir

I have a code to check if directory is empty, so that i will be able to perform actions, but this simple code gives an error:

> > **Warning:** opendir(/Site/images/countries/abc/a/2.swf,/Site/images/countries/abc/a/2.swf) [function.opendir]: The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\wamp\www\Site\index.PHP on line 374
> >
> > There is no such file

```
function IsNotEmpty($folder){
$files = array ();
if ( $handle = opendir ( $folder ) ) 
{
  while ( false !== ( $file = readdir ( $handle ) ) )
   {
      if ( $file != "." && $file != ".." ) 
         {
            $files [] = $file;
         }
   }

    closedir ( $handle ); 
 }
 return ( count ( $files ) > 0 ) ? TRUE: FALSE; }



 $dir ="/Site/images/countries/abc/a/2.swf";

 if (IsNotEmpty($dir)==true) 
     {
         echo "There is no such file";
 }
  else
     {
         echo "The file exists!";
     };
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. The file exits in the specified directory.

Answer (score 1):

`opendir` is for opening directories, not files :-)

You can also try temporarily putting in debug stuff so that you can see what's happening:

```
function IsNotEmpty ($folder) {
    $files = array ();
    if ($handle = opendir ($folder))  {
        echo "DEBUG opened okay ";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir ($handle))) {
            if ( $file != "." && $file != ".." ) {
                $files [] = $file;
                echo "DEBUG got a file ";
            }
        }
        closedir ($handle); 
    } else {
        echo "DEBUG cannot open ";
    }
    return (count($files) > 0 ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

$dir ="/Site/images/countries/abc/a";
if (IsNotEmpty($dir)) { 
    echo "There is no such file";
} else {
    echo "The file exists!";
}
```

If that's still not working and you're sure the directory exists (remember, case is important for UNIX), you may want to look into the permissions on that directory to ensure that the user ID trying to access it is allowed.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried using `$dir ="/Site/images/countries/abc/a/";` but it is the same error.

Comment: @Christine, if that is the case, then you need to check permissions as well.

Comment: @Christine, then you need to (1) check that the directory does indeed exists; and (2) check the the user has search (execute) rights to it. Perhaps a quick way to check would be to set `$dir = "/tmp";` temporarily since just about everyone should have search rights there.

Answer (score 0):

You chould use the following snippet as body for your function:

```
$aFiles = glob($sFolder);
return (sizeof($aFiles) < 1) true : false;
```

This will get the contents of the folder as an array, when empty - your directory is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try for instance this:

```
function IsNotEmpty($dir) {
      $dir = rtrim($dir, '/').'/';
      return is_dir($dir) && count(glob($dir.'*.*') > 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Christine, try removing the trailing slash:

```
$dir ="/Site/images/countries/abc/a/"
```

Becomes

```
$dir ="/Site/images/countries/abc/a"
```